# Identifying the coefficients of a principal component

Tags: self-study, pca, covariance

> Suppose that a two-dimensional random variable $X$ has a covariance matrix given by
>
> $$ \Sigma = \pmatrix {1 & -2\\ -2 & 4}$$
>
> One of the three linear combinations below corresponds to the first principal component. Without performing an eigen-decomposition of the covariance matrix, identify which linear combination corresponds to the first principal component, and justify your answer.
>
> Linear combination #1: $-0.447 X1 + 0.894 X2$
>
> Linear combination #2: $-0.894 X1 - 0.447 X2$
>
> Linear combination #3: $1.789 X1 + 1.789 X2$

I think I can safely eliminate #3 because the square of the coefficients needs to sum to 1. Both #1 and #2 have this property.

As the covariance between the two variables is negative, does this mean that the coefficients would have opposite signs i.e. #1?

Thanks

Comment: I think that your logic is correct; you actually answered your question. Your first statement (`sum to 1`) is actually unnecessary: it is true if the "coefficients" are defined as eigenvector elements and may not be true otherwise. The actual answer is in your last statement: if the covariance is negative, i.e. the variables as vectors has >90 degrees angle between them from geometric point of view, then the 1st PC which is the line along the maximal joint variance _should_ reflect that fact, by taking on coordinates of different sign.

Comment: ...One can observe also that the 3rd linear combination is wrong _because_ its coefficients are of equal magnitude. It is not possible since variances are unequal X2 is 4 times more variable and hence must be "stronger" in defining PC1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the determinant is zero we have only one factor. The variables are negatively correlated so their loadings must have different sign. So without checking the actual numbers, solution #1 is the only candidate. (The latter two arguments are equal to yours. The first argument is helpful here as we have a case, in which a further argument, that the alternating loadings are ***always*** in the first principal factor, is not needed. Such an argument needed reference to the eigendecomposition which should be avoided by the original question)

---

[update]: The sentence below was my first reasoning which implied an unnecessesary caution; I leave it here for reference to the first comment:

```
  The first argument is needed because if we had two factors it could possibly 
  happen that the first factor/first pc has equal signs on both variables and
  the second alternating signs)
```

The first argument is fine here, but the ***arguing for its importance*** is wrong.
It should go like this: having two items only the pc-factorization guarantees, that on each factor the ***squares*** of the item's loadings are equal, so their covariance is $r = a \cdot -a + b \cdot b$ with loadings of absolute values $a$ and $b$. To have negative correlation $-r$ by this sum, it is required that $a \gt b$ But then also $a^2+a^2 \gt b^2+b^2$ and thus the factor containing $a, -a$ is the first principal axis.
Unfortunately, this argument uses implicitely the knowledge of the eigenvalue-decomposition but which should be avoided by the requirements of the question....

Comment: +1, but... `if we had two factors it could possibly happen that the first factor/first pc has equal signs on both variables` makes me doubt. Can you show a 2x2 negative covariance matrix with both variables having the same sign in the first eigenvector?

Comment: You're correct; I can't find such a matrix. So this argument should be replaced by one which shows why such a case cannot happen. (I should have done the actual factorization before claiming)